# Sample code for iPhone location-based push notifications?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

There's something I'm not seeing with Apple's push notification programming guide & related documentation.  Is there a decent sample project (or well written tutorial) to show me how to do push location notifications?

Here's what I want to do:

- Launch my app.
- Press the "remember this spot" button.
- Quit my app.

  [... time passes ...]
- Get a notification: "You are now more than a mile from where you started."

  [... time passes ...]
- Get a notification: "You are now within 100' of where you started."

Apologies if this is covered in Apple's docs; I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks!

(Meta: Is there a way to withdraw a question once you realize that you're just being blind?)

Comment: How, exactly, would the phone track your location if you're not running the app any more?

Comment: @Adam iOS4 allows apps to run certain tasks in the background, including keeping an eye on the phone's location periodically.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Sorry, I didn't think of OS4 :). I read the "Quit my app" too literally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh.  And there it is.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

The problem was, I was searching on  "location + push notification" and coming up dry, I wanted "location aware."

Hopefully this entry will at least save someone else the trouble.

Comment: Ollie is it possible to do that if the application is killed? Or it should be in the background?

Comment: d0n, check the docs, but I believe that you are setting a system notification that tickles your app when the system becomes aware that the device has moved into or out of a certain radius from a target location.